# Creating a Multi-Level Associative Object Using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, javascript, json

I'd like to create a *Multi-Level Associative Object* on `$.post` method using WordPress, in order to make my code cleaner. The problem is, I don't know how to get those values to manipulate on the back-end.

This is what I would like to do in `my_query.js` file, which contains and handles the **AJAX** request.

```
$.post( MyAjax.ajaxurl, {
    action: 'my_action',
    someValue: {
        one: 'Some Value One',
        two: 'Some Value Two',
        three: 'Some Value Three',
        four: 'Some Value Four',
    }
} );
```

And this is the current solution, which I **DO NOT** want to implement on my code.

```
$.post( MyAjax.ajaxurl, {
    action: 'my_action',
    someValueOne: 'Some Value One',
    someValueTwo: 'Some Value Two',
    someValueThree: 'Some Value Three',
    someValueFour: 'Some Value Four'
} );
```

The only way I could get those values on the back-end is by using the second option and doing this in the `.php` file.

```
$someValue = array(
    'one'   => $_POST[ 'someValueOne' ],
    'two'   => $_POST[ 'someValueTwo' ],
    'three' => $_POST[ 'someValueThree' ],
    'four'  => $_POST[ 'someValueFour' ]
);

echo $someValue[ 'one' ];

wp_die();
```

## But... What is the problem anyways?

I **DO NOT** know how to have access to the **AJAX Data Object** inside my `.php` file by using the first example (which I'd like to), it only works by using the second one. How could I return the `someValue` object inside the `.php` file by using the first **AJAX Request** example?

Comment: when you try the associative array, what do you receive in `$_POST` ?

Comment: @mmm I receive the value passed in the **Data Object** inside the `$.post` method. In this case, I defined *Some Value One* in the **someValueOne** property, and as expected, I'm getting a *200* as **Response Status** and the property value perfectly.

Comment: @mmm I just noticed that if I run `return` it shows me 0 instead of the actual value, so I changed to `echo`.

Comment: you said that you receive the value so what is the problem ? please explain whit more details, show what you get and explain what you wish to get

Comment: @mmm Oh I thought you were asking what I was getting from using the second option not the first one. Well if you referred to the first one, I was that hoping you guys could tell me LoL, because I don't know if it's possible to access to data structured like that. I actually don't know how to manipulate the data from the **Data Object** on the **Back-End**. Do you got me?

Comment: just look what do you receive in $_POST (with http://php.net/print_r e.g.) and you will see if you find your datas

Comment: @mmm Look man, I don't know if you quite understood me, what I'm saying is that I can't have access to the **AJAX** data from the `.php` file using the first **AJAX Request** (which I want to). The only way I can `print_r` the data is by using the second one. The `.php` file still intact, did you get me now? I will try to clear that up on the question, ok?

Comment: I have understood that you want to access the data send by the first request then to help you, I want to known what is display by `print_r($_POST)` in this case

Comment: @mmm Sorry for feeding back you this late, but guess what? If I `print_r( $_POST  )` it actually returns an **Array** with all the data that I needed, for some reason I wasn't able to retrieve it before but now it works like a charm. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: this is the reason why I ask you to look this array for 3 days ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the solution I've found was very simple and didn't required much. For some reason I wasn't able to retrieve the data inside my **AJAX Function Request** on the Back-end.

### JavaScript Code

As you can see below I defined the `someValue` property just the way I wanted, very clean and pretty.

```
$.post( MyAjax.ajaxurl, {
    action: 'my_action',
    someValue: {
        one: 'Some Value One',
        two: 'Some Value Two',
        three: 'Some Value Three',
        four: 'Some Value Four'
    }
} );
```

### PHP Code

I must've forgot that I could associate all the properties defined inside the **Data Object** as an **Array** inside my Back-end *function*.

```
$someValue = array(
    'one'   => $_POST[ 'someValue' ][ 'one' ],
    'two'   => $_POST[ 'someValue' ][ 'two' ],
    'three' => $_POST[ 'someValue' ][ 'three' ],
    'four'  => $_POST[ 'someValue' ][ 'four' ]
);

wp_die();
```

If you are unsure about what kind of data you're getting from the **AJAX Request**. I recommend you to do what our friend [@mmm](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/74311/mmm) asked me, just `var_dump()` or `print_r()` the `$_POST` superglobal, then you'll see if you're actually getting something.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a complex value, your best path is probably to jsonify it. Something like

```
$.post( MyAjax.ajaxurl, {
    action: 'my_action',
    someValue: JSON.stringify({
        one: 'Some Value One',
        two: 'Some Value Two',
        three: 'Some Value Three',
        four: 'Some Value Four',
    })
} );
```

and then on the server side you decode the value with

`$someValue = json_decode($_POST['someValue']);`

At this point `$someValue` should be the array you wanted to pass.

Comment: Have you tested it? Just asking, because it didn't work, when I run `echo $someValue[ 'one' ]` it shows me nothing and when I run `return` it shows me `0`.

Comment: @iszwnc, obviously I have not tested it, answers on SE in general should be taken as a concept not as code you can assume that you can copy and paste.and it will work (although I will fix the answer if you find out what is wrong ;) )